# Machine Learning Model not Learning Correctly

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm building a simple linear regression model in TensorFlow JS and am having a bit of a problem with my model predicting things. I'm getting super sporadic and all over the place results (no where near what I'd expect) and I'm getting the feeling the model is not training correctly or something is definitely out of whack somewhere. Been stuck for a solid 6 hours now and have decided I should probably ask for help.

I'm importing my inputs and outputs from here:
https://storage.googleapis.com/jmstore/TensorFlowJS/EdX/TrainingData/real-estate-data.js

Inputs: Element 1 represents the size of a given property, element 2 represents the number of bedrooms
Outputs: Element 1 represents the cost of the home in $

So far, in order I have:
Defined my inputs and outputs
Written a function to normalise my inputs
Written a function to train model
Written a function to evaluate my model

I believe the model SHOULD be training correctly(?), however when evaluating my model my tensor output values are absolutely no where (finding the prediction is sometimes not even a whole number, sometimes it's 900 and sometimes it's as low as -1000). Hoping someone can point me in the right direction, I am fairly new to ML so do not have a lot of experience debugging. I've tried to play with the learn rate but haven't noticed any significant changes.

Also fully aware that trainModel(); is commented out, this code was pasted while trying to test it so did not need to reteach. The model has of course already been taught.

```
import { TRAINING_DATA } from "./data.js";

const inputs = tf.tensor2d(TRAINING_DATA.inputs);
const outputs = tf.tensor1d(TRAINING_DATA.outputs);

tf.util.shuffleCombo(inputs, outputs);

function normaliseData(input_tensor, min, max) {
  const result = tf.tidy(function () {
    const min_val = min || tf.min(input_tensor, 0);
    const max_val = max || tf.max(input_tensor, 0);
    const range_val = tf.sub(max_val, min_val);
    const minval_sub_tensor = tf.sub(input_tensor, min_val);
    const normalised_val = tf.div(minval_sub_tensor, range_val);
    // min_val.print(); // making sure values look ok
    // max_val.print(); // making sure values look ok
    // normalised_val.print(); // making sure values look ok
    return { normalised_val, min_val, max_val };
  });
  return result;
}

const values = normaliseData(inputs);

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(
  tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [2],
    units: 1,
  })
);

async function trainModel() {
  const learn_rate = 0.01;
  model.compile({
    optimizer: tf.train.sgd(learn_rate),
    loss: "meanSquaredError",
  });

  let result = await model.fit(values.normalised_val, outputs, {
    epochs: 10,
    batchSize: 32,
    validationSplit: 0.2,
    shuffle: true,
  });
  console.log("Model Trained!");
}

// trainModel();

function evaluateModel() {
  let newInput = normaliseData(
    tf.tensor2d([[1000, 2]]),
    values.min_val,
    values.max_val
  );
  let prediction = model.predict(newInput.normalised_val);
  prediction.print();
}

evaluateModel();
```

Comment: Bit of an idiot... was training the model then running my evaluate function separately which means the page refreshed and the model was no longer trained /facepalm - I've added buttons with event listeners now to trigger training and evaluate functions separately taking values from two input boxes for the 2d tensor input and it's working as expected now... hope this helps someone in the future just starting out in TF. You should save your trained model and then load it in your script unless you're only looking to run your model on the client side. Cheers...